# How do you interpret the data when all PCs show the same proportion of variance?

Tags: pca

I have a situation like this: The table is in the attached pic.

[image: pca table]

The co-variance matrix is not an identity matrix here.

[image: co-variance matrix]

Comment: Welcome to SE. What's your question? It's difficult to answer without knowing your question!!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are dealing with a data set of independent variables, i.e. the covariance matrix of your dataset is an identity matrix.